# Is Kodien verified at Compile Time?

Tags: android, ios, dependency-injection, kotlin-multiplatform, kodein

I am starting a new KMM project and I want to integrate a DI system. I found that there are 2 options: [Kodein](https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI) and [Koin](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin). Sadly Koin is not verified at compile time like Dagger and I was wondering if Kodein is verified at compile time ? Looking forward to your response and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither are verified at compile time. Koin can be verified at unit test time:

https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-test/checkmodules_plugin

Dagger-like stuff will probably wait on a compiler plugin style DI library, but we'll see.